# Application hangs forever when opening a Visio document

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop, visio

Here's my small bit of code.

```
protected void ViewVisio(string url)
{
    // open document
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visApp = 
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document visDoc =    // application hangs here
        visApp.Documents.Open(url);

    ...
}
```

Basically, the application just hangs forever on the line that opens the document. It never times out, even after a few hours, and it never throws an exception. I checked the Windows event logs, and there's nothing there.

I have Office installed on my server with all the correct permissions. I'm doing the same thing with Word, Excel, and PowerPoint files and they all work just fine, so I don't think it has anything to do with that.

So I'm at a bit of a loss here - anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: where does the document reside that you are trying to open..? can you refactor that code and wrap your code around a try{} catch{}..

Comment: try this link for starters I wonder if you are having a Path Issue.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160753.aspx

Comment: also take a look at this project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109558/Creating-VISIO-Organigrams-using-C

Comment: If you look in Windows Task Manager, does the Visio process launch?

Comment: Please read KB257757 carefully. I assume you get Word, Excel, PowerPoint working by running your ASP.NET application on ASP.NET Development Server (aka the toy server). If you run your app on IIS, then I think none of them works as you wished.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - yes, the process launches.

Comment: Have you modified the settings for Microsoft Visio Drawing in Component Services on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never run Microsoft Office under an automation context.  Microsoft does not recommend or support this (see KB257757 [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)).

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Comment: It's a pretty far gap from "not recommended or supported" to "*never*".  Rule number one in the business world is, your requirement will probably require you to do something hard and you better figure out how to do it.  I've written server-based conversions like this for Word and Powerpoint, and they work fine with a little bit of babysitting.  (log in once a week and kill any rogue processes)

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: I disagree.  While it's entirely possible, it's best to trust Microsoft here as they have invested a large amount of resources before reaching this conclusion.  It wasn't made ad hoc.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy, the truth is when Microsoft says it does not support (recommend), you should never. For example, if you open a support case and consult Microsoft on server side Office automation, the case might be rejected directly. You will get nothing from Microsoft except that KB257757.