# Visio Automation using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, iis-7.5, visio

I have recently developed an ASP.NET MVC project which supports uploading a visio(vsdx) file, reads the shapes information and performs some business operation.
The project works fine in the local but fails to work once deployed to IIS in windows server.

I tried configuring the com settings in DCOM Config, but Visio Drawing is not visible there.

Any particular settings to I need to perform for server ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application hangs forever when opening a Visio document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828946/application-hangs-forever-when-opening-a-visio-document)

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the same set of issues as of any other server-side office automation.

Microsoft has documented those about 15 years ago. Most of those are still valid.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

If you want to manipulate visio drawings server-side, better avoid automation.

Comment: Is there any other way you are aware of or would suggest to implement this ?
Basically I want to upload a visio file, parse & find the shapes used. That's it.